# RavenDB Query<T> Always Faster Than Load<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, ravendb

On the RavenDB site it says "Use Load over Query when you know the documents Id". In my tests on a simple collection of approximately 1,500 objects Load is always slower. Why?

Load:

```
var doc = session.Load<Document>("Documents/123");
```

Query

```
var doc = session.Query<Document>().Where(x => x.Id == "123").SingleOrDefault();
```

In a test, retrieving every document, the average Query time was 66 milliseconds vs 137 for the Load. The RavenDB instance is located in another office hence the high times. Regardless should Load not always be faster?

**Edit**

This is statement I'm referring to http://ravendb.net/kb/31/my-10-tips-and-tricks-with-ravendb. Tip #4. Is it wrong?

Comment: RavenDB 2.0+ will not *allow* you to query for an id.  So it's not just a best practice, it's a requirement.

Comment: @MattJohnson if you want to add that as an answer I'll choose it. I've actually thought of deleting this question but apparently others have the same issue. Perhaps this isn't documented thoroughly. Anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When retrieving an item by its `Id`, you are *required* to use the `.Load(id)` method.

`Load` is an [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant operation.  It retrieves documents directly from the document store.

`Query` is a [BASE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) operation that is "eventually consistent".  It goes first against an index, finds the documents in the document store, and then returns them.  Querying by an `Id` could potentially return null if the document was just added and has not been indexed yet.

RavenDB 2.0 added a feature to prevent you from querying by `Id`.  It will throw an exception if you try to do so.  So using `Load` is not just a best practice, it's a requirement.

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand, Load will guarantee to return a result (provided that id exists in the database) whereas Query might not return a result if the indexes haven't yet been updated.

You could have a scenario whereby you insert a record, then on the next line try to retrieve that same record using Query and then not get anything back. Load would return a record in this scenario.

So I guess the performance degradation you are seeing might be related to the fact that you are querying by index when using Query, whereas Load is hitting the actual data store.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and was my assumption but the 'Use Load over Query when you know the documents Id' on the RavenDB site led me to believe I was doing something wrong.